# What is Al Masjid Al Haram?

Tags: masjid

What is Al Masjid Al Haram? I remember it being mentioned several times in the Quran (I don't remember which Surah).

Comment: It is known that Masjid Al Haram is the masjid in Makkah.  We discourage questions here which could be answered by simply googling it, and we discourage questions in regards to common knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al-Masjid Al-Haram (The Sacred Mosque) is the mosque surrounding Al-Bayt Al-Haram (The Sacred House, i.e. Kaaba) in Mecca, Saudi Arabia.  It is in that direction that all Muslims are commanded to face when they perform their daily *salat*.

More details available at the Wikipedia page: [Masjid al-Haram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masjid_al-Haram)